Does Shadow Step work in concert with Find Familiar?
Shadow Step, the Way of Shadows Monk's 6th level feature, reads:

At 6th level, you gain the ability to step from one shadow into another. When you are in dim light or darkness, as a bonus action you can teleport up to 60 feet to an unoccupied space you can see that is also in dim light or darkness. You then have advantage on the first melee attack you make before the end of the turn.

Find Familiar reads (in part):

Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any special senses that the familiar has. During this time, you are deaf and blind with regard to your own senses.

Am I correct to infer that the use of the word "see" in the latter implies that Shadow Step can be used to teleport to a space that the familiar can see (so long as it's dark and the space is within 60 ft of the Monk)?  How does this work with other (admittedly less practical) means of "remote vision", such as Arcane Eye (which doesn't use the word "see") or Scrying (which does)?

Yes, this works
Find familiar says

Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes

So you are seeing through your familiars eyes, and you can shadow step to any space in dim light or darkness that you can see.
The seeing through your familiar's eyes costs an action, and the teleport with Shadow Step costs a bonus action, so the action economy also works1.  (All always provided your familiar's vision allows you to see in darkness, and the target space is in range2).
Scrying also just works, because it says

You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there.

You again can see the space, and there is no bonus action needed for that.
For arcane eye, the spell says:

You mentally receive visual information from the eye, which has normal vision and darkvision

That's a little bit more ambiguous than saying "you see" through the eye, probably because the spell does not say you lose the input from your normal senses, like find familiar does. I think its up to the DM if they count this as seeing or not - because you also receive visual information in your mind when you see, I‘d probably allow it, but another DM might not. If they rule it counts as seeing, this also works, because looking through the sensor does not even cost an action.

1 Having used your action, you will not have it available to attack with advantage any more, the second benefit of Shadow Step. The other methods do not need your action and do not suffer this drawback. Thanks to @MivaScott for calling this out.
2 Find familiar can only change the resolution of touch spells, which the familiar can deliver within 100 feet of you using its reaction. Shadow Step is not a touch spell, so the target space still must be within 60 feet of you, the caster, as you correctly posit in the question.

@fectin The question specifically says "within 60 feet of the monk".

@RyanC.Thompson fair enough.

As Nobody's answer points out, that yes, familiar's eyes, arcane eyes, and scrying eyes can see through these means, and so long as the place they are seeing is within 60 ft of the monk, they can Shadow Step.
However, it should be pointed out, that using a familiar nullifies part of feature. In order to see though a familiar's eyes, you need to use your Action.
So the monk, on their turn, use an Action to see the shadows that are visible to the familiar. Then as a Bonus Action, the monk Shadow Steps. But this means they no longer have an action that turn in which to attack with advantage (Unless they multi-class with Fighter and do an Action Surge).
Scrying and Arcane Eye do not have any description that says using them takes an Action, you just see. So those two, albeit more expensive, options would allow the monk to still attack after taking the step.

You're making the assumption that you use this ability during a fight as where I'd use it outside of combat. A spider familiar crawls under a door and the monk shadow steps into the locked room and unbolts the door for the rest of the party

@Honey Battery except shadow step is a bonus action so you can do both the same turn. If you're not in combat, it's not a turn based economy thus turns and actions don't apply.

@Thorne ah that's right, it is a Bonus, my bad. I'd still argue that by nature of the bond RAW a character isn't able to use anything that would require an action while they're seeing through the familiar, even if you're operating at the higher level of abstraction of no turns in an out of combat situation, but seems like it's entirely irrelevant to this case and I don't know with what other abilities this would even come into play.
